# How does the Python Runtime actually work?

Tags: python, runtime

I have some problems understanding the concept of a `runtime library`, especially the Python one.
So I have written some a hello world python program and intend to execute it, so I write `python ./hello_world.py`.

What steps happens between me hitting the Enter button and the machine code generated from my python code being executed on my CPU? And how does this relate to the Python runtime system and/or library?

Comment: These two threads give a great insight on Python runtime - [Is Python interpreted, or compiled, or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6889747/465053) & [Is Python interpreted (like Javascript or PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/745743/465053). Runtime and runtime library *aren't* the same. Mapping it to .NET world I know of - the Common Language Runtime (CLR) and Framework/Base Class Library (FCL/BCL) *aren't* the same.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For as diverse as they are, there are a handful of common concepts that all serious, modern programming languages share.  Two of them are the core of the answer for your questions above.

> What steps happens between me hitting the Enter button and the machine code generated from my python code being executed on my CPU?

The code gets parsed, analyzed, and fed into an interpreter.  This is all about a very important area of computer science known as *compiler theory*.  A compiler is a program that translates code from one language (your source code) to another language (typically machine code, though "transpilers" that translate from one high-level language to another do exist).  This is a really massive topic that you could spend years researching, but here's the basic version:

The compiler begins with a *parser*, a routine that reads your source code and applies the syntax rules of the language to it to figure out whether it makes sense as valid Python (in your case) code.  If it doesn't, the parser will throw an error and the compiler bails out, but if it does, the parser outputs what's known as an Abstract Syntax Tree, or AST for short.  The AST is a tree data structure whose nodes each contain an element of the syntax.  For example, if you say `x = 5`, you could end up with a `BinaryExpression` node with an `operator` value of `=`, a `Left` value of `ReferenceExpression(x)` and a `Right` value of `IntegerLiteralExpression(5)`.  Your whole program can be represented by a big tree like this.

Once the parser produces an AST, the second phase is *semantic analysis*.  In plain English, this means "figure out what this AST means."  It checks the AST to determine whether you did anything that's illegal even though it's a valid parse, (for example, trying to call a 1-argument function with 3 arguments,) and raises errors if you do.  Otherwise, it analyzes the AST and performs edits to it to make it simpler for a machine to understand.

The third phase is code generation.  Once you have a fully analyzed, simplified, valid AST, you feed it into the generator, which walks the AST and produces code in the output language.  This is your finished product.

With Python, it uses an interpreter rather than a compiler.  An interpreter works in exactly the same way as a compiler, with one difference: instead of code generation, it loads the output in-memory and executes it directly on your system.  (The exact details of how this happens can vary wildly between different languages and different interpreters.)

> And how does this relate to the Python runtime system and/or library?

All but the very simplest languages come with a set of predefined functions that are important to a large percentage of users and would be difficult for the users to implement on their own for one reason or another.  Their code can call into these functions without needing any third-party libraries.  (For example, in Python you have `print`, which sends output to `stdout`.  Good luck implementing that on your own!)  This set of functions is generally collected in a shared library that the code can call into at run-time, which is why it's known as the language runtime library, or simply "the runtime" for short.

Comment: So my code is fed to another program (the Python runtime system) that does all that and finishes when my code ends (and after the cleanup, of course)?

Comment: @hgiesel I believe that in Python's case, the interpreter is part of the runtime.  This is not the case for every language. of course, but it's fairly common among interpreted languages.

Comment: Nice explanation but some part of it seems wrong.Simply speaking, Python (CPython) is compiled to cpython bytecode (.pycfiles) which is then interpreted by cpython virtual machine.

Answer (score 6):

The standard Python implementation is a byte code virtual machine. This means that the *machine code* (opcodes from your processor's opcode set) is **not** generated from your program. The opcodes are only *selected* from the opcodes that are already compiled into the virtual machine while the VM interprets the byte code.

How your program is turned into byte code in the first place is a slightly different question, but the short answer is "through compiling, just like any other downward language translation".